# Reditied (New Question) :How to create (in QGIS) an "Other" value in the value map?

Tags: qgis-2.18

**Before you read: my apologies for grammar mistakes, English is not my native writing language and the spellcheck can only help me so far. I am learning QGIS completely on my own and I am trying to follow the training manual but that van only get me so far.**

Ok, so far I know how to create a value map with a list of value's to choose from with some attributes in the shapefile I can work in. This makes it easy for the person to add information to  green (were are working on a green database) objects such as author of the object. But I want to think a bit ahead by doing a little bit more than that. I know also to create a unique value list that can retyped. But I want to have a combination of both unique value and value map aka dropdown. Yeah I know you can add other values to a value map in value map edit menu. But considering that you this is gonna be linked to Qfield. I want to make it that way. Keep in mind the column that this setting must be created in is EMPTY. That means there are no current value's that can be set to Unique value's, and the value map is kind of already assigned.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  The tour states that there should be just one question per question, however you have asked multiple questions here, making it too broad.  Please [edit] your question to focus on one specific problem with details about what you've tried and what happens when you try it.  If you still need answers to your other questions, please ask them separately.

Comment: I redefined the question, this is now a new question, making this place still unresolved. Yes it is partially answered but it was not completely.

Answer (score 2):

**first situation:**

Use 'unique value' instead of 'value map'.  Already inserted authors will show up.
If you check 'editable' then new values can be added.

**second situation:**

same as first, but add some default value.
A screenshot wil explain

[image]

ps: It is better to update your QGIS to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the response I made a wrong label to the wrong version. My appologies.

Comment: Question is now unresolved, I thank you for the response but the question has been redefined.